# Sending emails on server errors in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, smtp

I have developed a web service for which I want to be notified when some server error occurs (ex. division by zero, out of memory exception, etc). I am wondering if is a good practice to handle and send this error for each request within a custom `ErrorHandler`?

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.api.OptionalSourceMapper;
import play.api.UsefulException;
import play.api.routing.Router;
import play.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

@Singleton
public class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

    @Inject
    public ErrorHandler(Configuration configuration, Environment environment, OptionalSourceMapper sourceMapper, Provider<Router> routes) {
        super(configuration, environment, sourceMapper, routes);
    }

    // Invoked in prod mode when a server error occurs.
    protected CompletionStage<Result> onProdServerError(RequestHeader request, UsefulException exception) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.internalServerError("A server error occurred (prod): " + exception.getMessage())
                // Send email
        );
    }

    protected CompletionStage<Result> onDevServerError(RequestHeader request, UsefulException exception) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
                Results.internalServerError("A server error occurred (dev): " + exception.getMessage())
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This may be useful for the non-fatal errors. But in case of fatal errors this will not work. Its better to use Logging and other process exception monitoring solutions.

Comment: At first I was thinking the same. I would just use logback and write a smtp appender that would be triggered on specific log-level messsages (in this case error messages). The problem I see here is that I cannot make a distiction between client and server errors (ex. in case of an invalid json an error would be logged but for this one I do not want to send an email). I could do it that way if Play would log fatal error but if I am not wrong that is not supported?

Comment: Use some specific tag in the logg to diffrentiate the log statements

Comment: Does that mean that for each controller I have to check for uncaught exception and then log them? Another option would be to set a default uncaught exception handler but I did not find any reference where to put it in play. In the first post you mentioned that fatal errors will not be handled by onProdServerError. Is that correct?

Comment: Have a common handle and based on type of exception use different tags. So that you can query later.When fatal error happens app stops working so even logger stop. Something like out of memory exception

Comment: You can also use logback filters to differentiate errors: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html